# SSDT project Post Deployment issues when seeding tables with foreign key constraints using Merge coupled with 'WHEN NOT MATCHED By SOURCE THEN DELETE'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSDT project and I seed the tables in my Script.PostDeployment.sql file using MERGE statements. The issue is when I have lookup tables which are dependent on each other and I remove records from those tables MERGE scripts then I get foreign key constraints.

Lets say I have two lookup tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent] (
  ParentId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child] (
  ChildId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  ParentId INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_Child] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([ParentId])
)
```

My Script.PostDeployment.sql script:

```
:r .\Parent.Seed.sql
:r .\Child.Seed.sql
```

My Parent.Seed.sql script

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Parent] ON
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Parent] as parent
  USING (VALUES (1,2,3)) seed ([ParentId])
  ON parent.ParentId = seed.ParentId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [ParentId] = seed.[ParentId]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT ([ParentId])
  VALUES ([ParentId])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Parent] OFF
GO
```

My Child.Seed.sql script:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Child] ON
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Child] as child
  USING (VALUES 
    (1,1)
    ,(2,2)
    ,(3,3)
  ) seed ([ChildId], [ParentId])
  ON child.ChildId = seed.ChildId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [ParentId] = seed.[ParentId]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT ([ChildId],[ParentId])
  VALUES ([ChildId],[ParentId])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Child] OFF
GO
```

This works fine the when initially seeding the database for the first time BUT when you modify the seed script because now lets say I want to remove the `3` record from the `Parent.Seed.sql` script then it throws a foreign key constraint error because it tries to remove the `ParentId` from the `Parent` table first, which violates the `[FK_Parent_Child]` constraint.

How can I manage these Lookup tables since they are always evolving as our application is evolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is few options:

1. Seed child table from a temp table instead of hardcoding values in merge.
   You will be able to do all modification in few steps and avoid FK violation, like insert parent, insert child, delete child, delete parent.
2. Disable FK constraint before the script and re-enable if after.
3. I'm not sure if it is a feasible in your case, you can try soft-delete (include deleted column in your tables).

Comment: These are such good solutions I feel stupid for not thinking of them before. Thank you!